# Material Design - Bootstrap Input Field Problem

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, material-design, bootstrap-5

This is MDB bootstrap Code which i got.

**Link for the Code** : [https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/standard/extended/login/#:~:text=EDIT%20IN%20SANDBOX-,Registration%20page,-Once%20again%2C%20the](https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/standard/extended/login/#:%7E:text=EDIT%20IN%20SANDBOX-,Registration%20page,-Once%20again%2C%20the)

```
<!-- Section: Design Block -->
<section class="background-radial-gradient overflow-hidden">
  <style>
    .background-radial-gradient {
      background-color: hsl(218, 41%, 15%);
      background-image: radial-gradient(650px circle at 0% 0%,
          hsl(218, 41%, 35%) 15%,
          hsl(218, 41%, 30%) 35%,
          hsl(218, 41%, 20%) 75%,
          hsl(218, 41%, 19%) 80%,
          transparent 100%),
        radial-gradient(1250px circle at 100% 100%,
          hsl(218, 41%, 45%) 15%,
          hsl(218, 41%, 30%) 35%,
          hsl(218, 41%, 20%) 75%,
          hsl(218, 41%, 19%) 80%,
          transparent 100%);
    }

    #radius-shape-1 {
      height: 220px;
      width: 220px;
      top: -60px;
      left: -130px;
      background: radial-gradient(#44006b, #ad1fff);
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    #radius-shape-2 {
      border-radius: 38% 62% 63% 37% / 70% 33% 67% 30%;
      bottom: -60px;
      right: -110px;
      width: 300px;
      height: 300px;
      background: radial-gradient(#44006b, #ad1fff);
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    .bg-glass {
      background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.9) !important;
      backdrop-filter: saturate(200%) blur(25px);
    }
  </style>

  <div class="container px-4 py-5 px-md-5 text-center text-lg-start my-5">
    <div class="row gx-lg-5 align-items-center mb-5">
      <div class="col-lg-6 mb-5 mb-lg-0" style="z-index: 10">
        <h1 class="my-5 display-5 fw-bold ls-tight" style="color: hsl(218, 81%, 95%)">
          The best offer <br />
          <span style="color: hsl(218, 81%, 75%)">for your business</span>
        </h1>
        <p class="mb-4 opacity-70" style="color: hsl(218, 81%, 85%)">
          Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
          Temporibus, expedita iusto veniam atque, magni tempora mollitia
          dolorum consequatur nulla, neque debitis eos reprehenderit quasi
          ab ipsum nisi dolorem modi. Quos?
        </p>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-6 mb-5 mb-lg-0 position-relative">
        <div id="radius-shape-1" class="position-absolute rounded-circle shadow-5-strong"></div>
        <div id="radius-shape-2" class="position-absolute shadow-5-strong"></div>

        <div class="card bg-glass">
          <div class="card-body px-4 py-5 px-md-5">
            <form>
              <!-- 2 column grid layout with text inputs for the first and last names -->
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 mb-4">
                  <div class="form-outline">
                    <input type="text" id="form3Example1" class="form-control" />
                    <label class="form-label" for="form3Example1">First name</label>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 mb-4">
                  <div class="form-outline">
                    <input type="text" id="form3Example2" class="form-control" />
                    <label class="form-label" for="form3Example2">Last name</label>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <!-- Email input -->
              <div class="form-outline mb-4">
                <input type="email" id="form3Example3" class="form-control" />
                <label class="form-label" for="form3Example3">Email address</label>
              </div>

              <!-- Password input -->
              <div class="form-outline mb-4">
                <input type="password" id="form3Example4" class="form-control" />
                <label class="form-label" for="form3Example4">Password</label>
              </div>

              <!-- Checkbox -->
              <div class="form-check d-flex justify-content-center mb-4">
                <input class="form-check-input me-2" type="checkbox" value="" id="form2Example33" checked />
                <label class="form-check-label" for="form2Example33">
                  Subscribe to our newsletter
                </label>
              </div>

              <!-- Submit button -->
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block mb-4">
                Sign up
              </button>

              <!-- Register buttons -->
              <div class="text-center">
                <p>or sign up with:</p>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-link btn-floating mx-1">
                  <i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i>
                </button>

                <button type="button" class="btn btn-link btn-floating mx-1">
                  <i class="fab fa-google"></i>
                </button>

                <button type="button" class="btn btn-link btn-floating mx-1">
                  <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>
                </button>

                <button type="button" class="btn btn-link btn-floating mx-1">
                  <i class="fab fa-github"></i>
                </button>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<!-- Section: Design Block -->
```

Here when input fields are filled with data the placeholder returning to the same place even after entering the required fields !
What the code should do -> the placeholder should not come back to the normal place when the input fields are Entered !

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<input>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-input-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification. The same is true for all HTML tags including `<br>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding `data-mdb-input-init` attribute to each `form-outline` (also, it creates a border on input):

example:

```
 <div class="form-outline" data-mdb-input-init>
    <input type="text" id="form3Example1" class="form-control" />
    <label class="form-label" for="form3Example1">First name</label>
  </div>>
```

MDB docs working example:

https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/standard/forms/input-fields/

demo:

```html
<!-- Font Awesome -->
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- Google Fonts -->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- MDB -->
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdb-ui-kit/7.0.0/mdb.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />




<!-- Section: Design Block -->
<section class="background-radial-gradient overflow-hidden">
  <style>
    .background-radial-gradient {
      background-color: hsl(218, 41%, 15%);
      background-image: radial-gradient(650px circle at 0% 0%, hsl(218, 41%, 35%) 15%, hsl(218, 41%, 30%) 35%, hsl(218, 41%, 20%) 75%, hsl(218, 41%, 19%) 80%, transparent 100%), radial-gradient(1250px circle at 100% 100%, hsl(218, 41%, 45%) 15%, hsl(218, 41%, 30%) 35%, hsl(218, 41%, 20%) 75%, hsl(218, 41%, 19%) 80%, transparent 100%);
    }
    
    #radius-shape-1 {
      height: 220px;
      width: 220px;
      top: -60px;
      left: -130px;
      background: radial-gradient(#44006b, #ad1fff);
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    #radius-shape-2 {
      border-radius: 38% 62% 63% 37% / 70% 33% 67% 30%;
      bottom: -60px;
      right: -110px;
      width: 300px;
      height: 300px;
      background: radial-gradient(#44006b, #ad1fff);
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    .bg-glass {
      background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 100%, 0.9) !important;
      backdrop-filter: saturate(200%) blur(25px);
    }
  </style>

  <div class="container px-4 py-5 px-md-5 text-center text-lg-start my-5">
    <div class="row gx-lg-5 align-items-center mb-5">
      <div class="col-lg-6 mb-5 mb-lg-0" style="z-index: 10">
        <h1 class="my-5 display-5 fw-bold ls-tight" style="color: hsl(218, 81%, 95%)">
          The best offer <br />
          <span style="color: hsl(218, 81%, 75%)">for your business</span>
        </h1>
        <p class="mb-4 opacity-70" style="color: hsl(218, 81%, 85%)">
          Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Temporibus, expedita iusto veniam atque, magni tempora mollitia dolorum consequatur nulla, neque debitis eos reprehenderit quasi ab ipsum nisi dolorem modi. Quos?
        </p>
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-6 mb-5 mb-lg-0 position-relative">
        <div id="radius-shape-1" class="position-absolute rounded-circle shadow-5-strong"></div>
        <div id="radius-shape-2" class="position-absolute shadow-5-strong"></div>

        <div class="card bg-glass">
          <div class="card-body px-4 py-5 px-md-5">
            <form>
              <!-- 2 column grid layout with text inputs for the first and last names -->
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 mb-4">
                  <div class="form-outline" data-mdb-input-init>
                    <input type="text" id="form3Example1" class="form-control" />
                    <label class="form-label" for="form3Example1">First name</label>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 mb-4">
                  <div class="form-outline" data-mdb-input-init>
                    <input type="text" id="form3Example2" class="form-control" />
                    <label class="form-label" for="form3Example2">Last name</label>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

              <!-- Email input -->
              <div class="form-outline mb-4" data-mdb-input-init>
                <input type="email" id="form3Example3" class="form-control" />
                <label class="form-label" for="form3Example3">Email address</label>
              </div>

              <!-- Password input -->
              <div class="form-outline mb-4" data-mdb-input-init>
                <input type="password" id="form3Example4" class="form-control" />
                <label class="form-label" for="form3Example4">Password</label>
              </div>

              <!-- Checkbox -->
              <div class="form-check d-flex justify-content-center mb-4">
                <input class="form-check-input me-2" type="checkbox" value="" id="form2Example33" checked />
                <label class="form-check-label" for="form2Example33">
                  Subscribe to our newsletter
                </label>
              </div>

              <!-- Submit button -->
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block mb-4">
                Sign up
              </button>

              <!-- Register buttons -->
              <div class="text-center">
                <p>or sign up with:</p>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-link btn-floating mx-1">
                  <i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i>
                </button>

                <button type="button" class="btn btn-link btn-floating mx-1">
                  <i class="fab fa-google"></i>
                </button>

                <button type="button" class="btn btn-link btn-floating mx-1">
                  <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>
                </button>

                <button type="button" class="btn btn-link btn-floating mx-1">
                  <i class="fab fa-github"></i>
                </button>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<!-- Section: Design Block -->

<!-- MDB -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdb-ui-kit/7.0.0/mdb.umd.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @Yogi thanks. I thought the same, but then I looked around, and found out it's actually working normally (and somewhat documented) here: https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/standard/forms/input-fields/. Well, the examples are definitely buggy., and I didn't find this crucial info about the attribute anywhere..

Answer (score 0):

Even after applying @traynor's code suggestion, if you are still facing the issue, check if you have the MDB JavaScript library included and initialized properly.

for example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdb-ui-kit/7.1.0/mdb.umd.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```